# Método OnMouseUp() não funciona no unity4

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá!
Sou novo em Unity e não consigo fazer o método OnMouseUp(); funcionar

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 public class touch : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnMouseUp() {

        Debug.Log("Drag ended!");
    }}
```

Eu já atribuí o script ao objeto. Clico nele e nada acontece. Alguém sabe me explicar porque não funciona?

Comment: O teu objecto tem um Collider ou um GUIElement?

Comment: O colega @lazyFox muito provavelmente acertou o motivo. Veja na [documentação do método](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html), onde diz claramente: "*This event is sent to all scripts attached to the Collider or GUIElement.*"

Comment: Aliás, @lazyFox, você já poderia fornecer uma resposta com base na sua colocação. :)

Comment: Olá amigos! obrigado pelas dicas achei um tutorial aqui https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52U-eCAeGSo

Comment: Olá Emerson. Você conseguiu resolver o seu problema com esse tutorial? Se sim, por favor, crie uma resposta você mesmo explicando (não basta só apontar o tutorial!) qual era o problema e como você o resolveu. Isso pode ajudar outras pessoas no futuro, e justifica manter a sua questão aqui no site. :)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a documentação da Unity, para que o evento **OnMouseUp** funcione, o mesmo deve estar em um objeto que contenha um **Collider** ou **GUIElement**.

Para maiores informações, segue a documentação: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html